# Create combo box and populate items dynamically

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a combo box (cboTable) that contains list of database tables. When I select a table, it should generate a number of combo boxes that contains table columns name. If the table has 4 columns then 4 combo boxes should be created with each of columns name as the default value of each combo box.

I want to change the current codes so I can create combo boxes and populate its items dynamically. Could someone helps me to do this? Thank you.

```
 private void cboTable_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TableID = cboTable.SelectedItem.ToString();
        SqlCommand cmd;
        SqlDataReader dr;

        SqlConnection CS = new SqlConnection();
        CS.ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conel"].ConnectionString;
        cmd = new SqlCommand("select Column_name from Information_schema.columns where Table_name = @TableID");
        CS.Open();
        cmd.Connection = CS;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TableID", cboTable.SelectedItem.ToString());
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        

        cboON1.Items.Clear();
        cboON2.Items.Clear();
        cboON3.Items.Clear();
        cboON4.Items.Clear();

        while (dr.Read())
        {
            cboON1.Items.Add(dr["Column_name"]);
            cboON2.Items.Add(dr["Column_name"]);
            cboON3.Items.Add(dr["Column_name"]);
            cboON4.Items.Add(dr["Column_name"]);
        }

        cboON1.SelectedIndex = 0;
        cboON2.SelectedIndex = 1;
        cboON3.SelectedIndex = 2;
        cboON4.SelectedIndex = 3;

        CS.Close();

    }
```

I created the following codes but it only populate column names in the first combo box while the other comboboxes are empty.

```
for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
            {
                ComboBox cb = new ComboBox();
                cb.Location = new Point(475, 25 * i + 210);
                switch (i)
                {
                    case 0:
                        cb.Click += new EventHandler(ButtonClick2);
                        break;

                }

                this.Controls.Add(cb);
                while (dr.Read()) 
                {
                     cb.Items.Add(dr["Column_name"]);
                }
                
            }
```

Comment: Without a [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem, it's impossible to know what the problem is for sure. But: I don't see any code here that resets the data reader. So after the first combo box, there's nothing left to read. If you want to populate the combo boxes identically, why not just read the column names into a list, and then use the list as the data source for the combo boxes, all of them?

Comment: When will case i==0 be true in this for loop? Also, you would be better served by making a List<ComboBox> to store these rather than trying to refer to objects created at execution time by name.

Comment: Most times that I've seen people create UIs that are like "map the fields of your csv file to the columns of the database table for a bulk load" they use a pair of listboxes and equalize the column counts with (ignore) type items then arrange the mapping by having the user reorder the items. I'm struck that you could also do what you want fairly easily with a datagridview, in either a horizontal or vertical orientation. Would an answer describing any of those suit your needs or are you hard set on having comboboxes directly on a form?

Comment: @CaiusJard Yes, I agree that using a datagridview is the easier way. However, my boss asked me to provide comboboxes for the comparison.

Comment: I mean a datagridview can contain conboboxes... it would make life a lot easier